# Indenting list items with fontawesome icon

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to make my list items with fontawesome icons look like this:

[image]

but at the moment, they look like this:

[image]

Here my HTML:

```
<section id="black-studio-tinymce-6" class="widget widget_black_studio_tinymce">
  <h2 class="widget-title">Contact Us</h2>
  <div class="textwidget">
    <ul>
      <li>021 552 1187</li>
      <li>info@powersol.co.za</li>
      <li>Unit S19 Spearhead Business Park<br>
        cnr Montague Drive &amp; Freedom Way<br>
        Montagu Gardens<br>
        Cape Town, South Africa</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here my styling:

```
section#black-studio-tinymce-6 div.textwidget ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  li {
    &:first-child:before {
      @extend .font-awesome-footer;
      content: '\f095';
    }

    &:nth-child(2):before {
      @extend .font-awesome-footer;
      content: '\f003';
    }

    &:last-child:before {
      @extend .font-awesome-footer;
      content: '\f041';
    }
  }
}
```

How can indent the content after the fontawesome links as the picture shows?
Hope you can help.

Comment: group your `li:before` into one and extend `.font-awesome-footer` to save space, and I think you should consider use only `nth-child` for more consistent code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's very easy to solve:

Add some padding to the list items and position your icons absolute in that padding area.

```
li {
    padding-left: 40px;
    position: relative;
    &::before {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I know, it's an old thread, but now the solution is better and cleaner.

You should use **fa-ul** and **fa-li**

**List Icons** examples:

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span>List icons can</li>
    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span>be used to</li>
    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></span>replace bullets</li>
    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-square"></i></span>in lists</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use margin-left: 10px; but that would not work since the icons one the left all have different length so do something like this for each child:

```
margin-right: 800px;
```

make changes to 800px which can suit you the most